# How can I send email from WatchOS2 app?

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, ios9, watchos-2

I am trying to use the following code but its not working:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"mailto:first@example.com?cc=second@example.com,third@example.com&subject=Hello%20from%20California!"];
[[WKExtension sharedExtension] openSystemURL:url];
```